# error when preparing nested foreach loops for R package compile

Tags: r, foreach, r-package

Easiest way to describe this is show the code.  I have a nested foreach loop that works fine, trying to prepare to compile as an R package, thus remove "library(foreach)" in the code.  My function looks like this:

```
Calcs <- function (...) {
results <- data.frame (foreach::foreach (j = 1:NumSim, .combine = acomb,
                                .options.mpi=opts1)
                       %:%
                       foreach::foreach (i = 1:PopSize, .combine=rbind,
                                .options.mpi=opts2,
                                .export = c (ls(globalenv())),
                                .packages = c("zoo", "msm", "FAdist"))
                       foreach::`%dopar%` {


                           output <- if(rbinom(1,1,ProSecPos) > 0)
                                  replicate(DayNum, eval(call("PrbInfBep")))
                                  else rep(0, DayNum)

                           output2 <- data.frame(khf(output))
                       }
                       )
```

}

I get an "unexpected symbol" error at the start of the second "foreach:foreach" statement like this.

```
  ./functions/Parallel.R:19:28: unexpected symbol
18:                                     .packages = c("zoo", "msm", "FAdist"))
19:                            foreach
                               ^
```

For some strange reason it seems happy with the "%:%", or it just hasn't worked back to that error yet.  Do I need something clever like `foreach::foreach::`%dopar%`

Comment: Thx, tried it and now get this message "Error in foreach::foreach(j = 1:NumSim, .combine = acomb, .options.mpi = opts1) %:%  : 
  could not find function "%dopar%"  ", I'm following a previous solution on here where they did solve the problem by using      foreach::`%doapr`    but it won't work for me.  To be clear, I'm not building package yet, just trying to get code to run without loading entire package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `foreach` use some non-standard evaluation so that it is not straightforward to use in a package just by adding `foreach::` before everything. What you could easily do instead is to use `#' @import foreach` in the **roxygen2** documentation.

If you really want to use `foreach::`, you could but it is not pretty. For example, if you want to transform

```
library(foreach)
test1 <- foreach::foreach (j = 1:20, .combine = c) %:%
  foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = c) %do% {
    i * j 
  }
```

you can do

```
test2 <- foreach::`%do%`(
  foreach::`%:%`(foreach::foreach(j = 1:20, .combine = c),
                 foreach::foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = c)), 
  {
    i * j 
  }
)

all.equal(test1, test2)
```

PS: you will have a NOTE complaining about `i` and `j`. To remove it, you can add `globalVariables(c("i", "j"))` somewhere in your package.

Comment: That worked great, and you are correct, it is not pretty, and a bit difficult to follow the logic and syntax ... but it works.  Well done.

Comment: Actually, the logic is understandable with the documentation :')

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, can you send us a link to the documentation, I couldn't find it!

Comment: `?foreach::foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Int he second foreach you dont have a %:% after it. Please try with this notation...

For nested foreach you should use always:

```
matrix<-foreach()%:%
foreach()%:%
foreach()%dopar%{

}
```

Comment: Thx ... the correct notation for "nested" foreach loops is  foreach (...) %:% foreach (...) %dopar% {  } , the %:% is the "nested" operator, and has worked correctly for me for years.  I've done exactly what you say, except you show 3 levels of nesting, mine only has two .... I think.